# how to parse RAW AAC header like this "13 88 e5 56 a0"

Tags: aac

I have got RAW AAC datas from demuxer, but I do not know how to parse the header of it. The header is 5 bytes like this "13 88 e5 56 a0"

Comment: Your entry point for AAC: [Information technology — Coding of audio-visual objects — Part 3: Audio](https://www.google.com/search?q=ISO/IEC+14496-3)

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be trying to do is decoding the AAC audio. To be able to do that you need the AAC specification: "ISO/IEC 14496-3:2009 Information technology -- Coding of audio-visual objects -- Part 3: Audio".

The specification is not free, but if you just want an overview you can find older document [drafts](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Advanced_Audio_Coding) for free.